# Alternative for bridge mode

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, home-networking, dhcp

Up until now, I have been managing my own private network by setting my ISP's modem to bridge mode. However, recently I switched my ISP and now I received a modem with rather limited options. I can barely do anything on this new router.

Now what I want, is to be able to configure the DNS server on my own router. The only problem is that I cannot switch DHCP off on the ISP router. My question is then, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: You shouldn't have to disable DHCP on the ISP router if the only device connected to it is an actual router you can configure.

Comment: I'm guessing DHCP enabled here should be more properly referred as NAT on.  Sort of hard to redirect a port on the WAN into some host in the LAN like is typical for NAT routers these days if it's a double NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Chain the routers so your router's "uplink" port connects to the NAT ports of the ISP router.  Then, DON'T use any of the other ports on the ISP's router.  Use only the ports on your own router.

For sanity's sake, make sure the DHCP subnets of the two routers are of different ranges.